# Javascript onclick event in a loop executed more than 1 time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, cookies

When a user click on my html button, the onclick event is executed 10 times. I do not really understand why. I create an html button dynamically to be added to 10 elements because

```
divs.length = 10
```

Here is the code of my function:

```
function addButton(){
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll (".posted-on"); 
    for (i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
        //new title and news url 
        var newsTitle = divs[i].parentNode.previousElementSibling.textContent;
        var newsLink = divs[i].parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
        //html button creation
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        var textenode = document.createTextNode('add me');
        button.appendChild(textenode);
        //ad listener on the button for an onclick event
        button.onclick = setNewCookie(newsTitle, newsLink, 'localhost', '/');
        //insert button after the element <span class="posted-on"></span>
        divs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(button, divs[i].nextSibling);        
    }
}
```

I see the onclick function is called 10 times because when I click once I see 10 cookies in my browser. Each of those cookies represents 10 different news items (who are the 10 news title of my WordPress homepage)

Here is the code of the function setNewCookie:

```
    function setNewCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, domainValue, pathValue){
    var cook = (cookieName); 
    var val = (cookieValue);
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
    document.cookie = cook +"=" + val + ";expires=" + myDate + "; domain="+domainValue+"; path="+pathValue+"; ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code.

**Problem** - you invoke 'setNewCookie' as set the value as the 'onclick' property, instad of setting 'setNewCookie' as the property.

**Solution** - we wrap the function with anonymous function.

**Problem** - you use the same variables in 'for' loop, the value of the variable in the onClick callback will be the last value you set to them when the callback invoke.

**Solution** - we invoke anonymous function that gets the variables we get using the 'for' loop, so the value will remain the same in the 'scope' and returning the function wrapped with another anonymous function 
replace

```
button.onclick = setNewCookie(newsTitle, newsLink, 'localhost', '/');
```

with

```
button.onclick = (function(newsTitle, newsLink){
   return function(){
        setNewCookie(newsTitle, newsLink, 'localhost', '/');
  };
})(newsTitle, newsLink);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it solved the problem ! 
May I ask you something else ? my cookies title are written in french. Sometime the title of my news is a string with french character like "é" or ù but in my cookies I have a specials symbol instead of french character  (maybe unicode reprensation ?) Can you tell me what can I do to be able to get my cookies with french character ?

Comment: I voted for you answer but the system tells me I need to have a reputation of 15. You helped me a lot !

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I don't know the answer to the cookie question.